# OpenGL drawing code is not drawing anything

Tags: java, android, android-studio, opengl-es

I have a method that is supposed to draw a single reel of a slot machine, but it doesn't seem to be drawing anything I can see:

```
   void drawreel(GL10 gl) {
        float increment = 0.03f;

        for (float angle = 0; angle < 2.0f * Math.PI; angle += increment) {
            FloatBuffer vfb = MyDirectBuffer.getFloatBuffer(100);
            FloatBuffer tfb = MyDirectBuffer.getFloatBuffer(100);
            FloatBuffer nfb = MyDirectBuffer.getFloatBuffer(100);

            float y = (float) Math.sin(angle);
            float z = (float) Math.cos(angle);
            float texturey = (float) (1.0f - angle / (2.0f * Math.PI));

            texturey = getYtexture(texturey);

            tfb.put(0);
            tfb.put(texturey);

            nfb.put(0);
            nfb.put(y);
            nfb.put(z);

            vfb.put(-0.39f);
            vfb.put(y);
            vfb.put(z);

            tfb.put(1);
            tfb.put(texturey);

            nfb.put(0);
            nfb.put(y);
            nfb.put(z);

            vfb.put(0.39f);
            vfb.put(y);
            vfb.put(z);

            float nexty = (float) Math.sin(angle + increment);
            float nextz = (float) Math.cos(angle + increment);

            texturey = (float) (texturey - increment / (2 * Math.PI));

            tfb.put(1);
            tfb.put(texturey);

            nfb.put(0);
            nfb.put(nexty);
            nfb.put(nextz);

            vfb.put(0.39f);
            vfb.put(nexty);
            vfb.put(nextz);

            tfb.put(0);
            tfb.put(texturey);

            nfb.put(0);
            nfb.put(nexty);
            nfb.put(nextz);

            vfb.put(-0.39f);
            vfb.put(nexty);
            vfb.put(nextz);

            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            //gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            //gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);


            gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, tfb);
            gl.glNormalPointer(GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, nfb);
            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vfb);

            gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
            int error = gl.glGetError();

            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


        }


    }
```

Also, here is another method that gets called:

```
    static FloatBuffer getFloatBuffer(int numFloats)
    {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(numFloats);
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer newFloatBuffer = buffer.asFloatBuffer();
        return newFloatBuffer;
    }
```

I called glGetError, and it seems to always return 0, indicating no error.

Anyone know how I can figure out why nothing seems to be drawing in drawreel?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you succeed drawing a simple triangle before (e.g. by following a tutorial) or did you just jump into more complex drawing? Without knowing more about your code it's hard to tell what's going on but since you're not getting any errors this might be more of a problem that OpenGL can't detect. Issues that I can think of right off the top of my head: 1) your view/screen projection might be wrong 2) you're winding your triangles in the wrong direction and thus run into back face culling 3) you didn't set up material or lighting properly 4) the texture contains a all 0 alpha channel (unlikely)

Comment: Oh btw, I'd assume you would want to initialize your buffers _before_ the loop and call your drawing code _after_ the loop. That might actually be your biggest issue. - Also: why are your x-coodinates all fixed but alternating between positive and negative values?

Comment: Well, there's a lot going on, so boiling it down to something more simple is always a good idea. In any case, I don't see where you are building your shaders, what your shader code looks like, or creating VAOs or anything like that, so you would need to provide that.

Comment: Is the reel perpendicular to the view? What happens if you do `vfb.put(z); vfb.put(y); vfb.put(0);`

Comment: I posted the code over here: http://www.mediafire.com/file/lvabewbsu9kb1ua/NewSlotMachine.zip/file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by making sure this code was there:

```
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
            tfb.position(0);
            nfb.position(0);
            vfb.position(0);
```

The FloatBuffers needed to be rewinded back to 0.
Plus, for the slot machine to draw right, I needed to enable all three client states.